# Ansible configuration failed in Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible, ubuntu-16.04

Im new to Devops and im learning the Ansible as a beginner with AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

initially i have launched 2 EC2 instances with SSH port 22 open in security group, i named the instances as **Master** and **Slave**.

I ssh'ed into **Master** Instances when all is up and running.
I will list steps  one by one as follow

**1. I created a user called *ansible* and issued password**

```
 ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-94:~$ sudo su
    root@ip-172-31-17-94:/home/ubuntu# adduser ansible 
Adding user `ansible' ...
Adding new group `ansible' (1001) ...
Adding new user `ansible' (1001) with group `ansible' ...
Creating home directory `/home/ansible' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for ansible
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: 
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n]
```

**2. uncommented PermitRootLogin yes and PasswordAuthentication yes in */etc/ssh/sshd_config* and restarted ssh**

**3.Changed the Visudo file adding root access to *ansible* user**

```
root@ip-172-31-17-94:/home/ubuntu# visudo
```

edited

```
  # User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
ansible ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

saved and closed

**4.Generated ssh keygen**

```
ansible@ip-172-31-17-94:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/ansible/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:wah0yD9Ngf7hzLIihkEFvNYjPNrzcLubNxGnqFKYrik ansible@ip-172-31-17-94
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 4096]----+
|...    ..        |
| . o ..o .       |
|. + +.o +        |
| B + +ooo.       |
|++o o.oOS.       |
|= = o +.=        |
|.+ * . +         |
|Eo+ +.+          |
|=o .+= .         |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

**5. Installing Ansible packages**

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ansible
```

Awesome!.. all is up and ansible is install in master server 
I issued a command to test the ansible

```
ansible@ip-172-31-17-94:~$ ansible --version 
ansible 2.3.0.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

**6. Edited the */etc/ansible/hosts* and added my slave server private ip (My ec2 are in same subnet in same availability zone ) so i used private Ip**

> [my]
>
> 172.31.29.197
>   .save and closed

**7.ssh'ed in *Slave* Server and repeated the *1, 2 ,3* steps and logout**

**8.shh'ed  into *Master* server**

```
local@host $ shh ansible@<Master Ip>
```

**9.Copying public Key to the *Slave* Server from *Master* server**

```
ansible@ip-172-31-17-94:~$ ssh-copy-id 172.31.29.197
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
The authenticity of host '172.31.29.197 (172.31.29.197)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:qOW0ZktetcpTNmxRsubxn1kcr8egyNmcA5Uk9+oWc7A.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
ansible@172.31.29.197's password: 

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh '172.31.29.197'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added 


ansible@ip-172-31-17-94:~$ ssh 172.31.29.197
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1013-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

14 packages can be updated.
12 updates are security updates.


Last login: Sat Apr 22 06:27:15 2017 from 42.109.141.238
ansible@ip-172-31-29-197:~$ logout
Connection to 172.31.29.197 closed.
```

And successfully configured the **Mater** to  **Slave** password-less ssh connection

Till then i haven't faced any issue.
when i issued a command `Ansible -m ping all`
i got an error

```
172.31.29.197 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 172.31.29.197 closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 0
}
```

later when i gooogled i got some chunks i followed listed step by the solution.
the solution is i repeated **step no.5** from above list  in **slave** server. when issued `ansible -m ping` from the **Master** server i got **success Message**

**My question that how to install agent-less anible in a *Slave*, The main feature of *ansible* agent-less!**

*Help me if i missed any of step*

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Python 2 on 172.31.29.197.

Or (in a less likely case) if it is installed in a path different than `/usr/bin/python` you need to add `ansible_python_interpreter` parameter pointing to the right executable to your inventory file.